# Неконсольное приложение на С++

Tags: c++

Как можно создать приложение на С++ не на консоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это от целевой операционной системы зависит. Если нужна Windows, то мастер проектов Visual Studio - это то, что нужно. Перед тем как начать, стоит ознакомиться с статьями справки:

- [Приступая к работе с Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualc/ee340952.aspx)
- [Пошаговые руководства по Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e6w9eycd.aspx)
- [Интерактивный учебник по Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235630.aspx)

и наконец:

- [Creating Win32-Based Applications (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb384843.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Использовать произвольную графическую библиотеку. В принципе, никто не мешает делать вручную вызовы необходимых Win32 API функций, но это весьма муторно. Просто смысл использовать Win32 API с ООП-языков типа C++? Проще найти готовую библиотеку классов.
А таковых есть множество.

- VCL в Borland (ныне - Embarcadero) C++ Builder
- MFC в MS Visual Stusio
- Ранее еще был OWL из Borland C++ 5.xx (не билдер!!!), но в связи с неактуальностью последнего, к использованию не рекомендую.
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), который можно прикрутить к любой среде и компилятору C++
- [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
- [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)

Последние три даже кроссплатформенные, т.е. позволяют писать графические приложения под многие операционные системы, не зацикливаясь на Windows. Можно также обратить внимание, что VCL и MFC привязаны до определенной степени к среде программирования, с которой они были сделаны. Это и логично. Потому что среда позволяет рисовать те же окна, а чтобы с помощью библиотеки их можно было отобразить, нужно чтобы все было разработчиком правильно скомпоновано. Хотя все равно все сводится к ресурсам приложений, которые стандартны для определенной ОС. И их можно собирать вручную. Но проще процесс автоматизировать.

Comment: Embarcadero выпускает ещё и кроссплатформенную гуи библиотеку [FireMonkey](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireMonkey) (FMX).

Answer (score 0):

Консольное приложение от не консольного отличается типом используемой подсистемы, которая в пе-хидере определена(нэйтив, гуй, консольная etc). Это всего два бита.

Comment: Получается, этот бит можно задать указав опцию для компоновщика. НО! Консольные приложения по идее могут иметь дополнительные графические окна. И messagebox'ы они тоже умеют отображать. Так что это не критерий :-( А приложений с флагом Native я вообще на практике не наблюдал.

Comment: Разумеется это гуи-приложение. Просто при запуске такого процесса сервер(csrss) создаст консоль. Тоже что вы вызовите AllocConsole(). Разницы нет никакой. Едиснтвенно это редирект вывода в файл, для этого необходимо указать опцию Subsystem:CUI. И консолей в одном процессе может быть множество.

Comment: Флаг Native можно углядеть в ntoskrnl.exe =)